# Query to retrieve sum of values from two tables

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables

persons

```
----------------------------
| name       | nationality |
----------------------------
| Manuel     | Spanish     |
| Juan       | Spanish     |
| Marye      | Dutch       |
| Liza       | Dutch       |
| John       | English     |
| Mr. Stingy | Stingish    |
----------------------------
```

trades

```
--------------------------------
| id | seller | buyer  | value |
--------------------------------
| 1  | Marye  | Juan   |   100 |
| 2  | John   | Manuel |    30 |
| 3  | John   | Manuel |    50 |
| 4  | John   | Marye  |    10 |
| 5  | Juan   | Lisa   |    30 |
--------------------------------
```

I want to make a query in which I retrieve the value bought and sold per nationality. So the output would be something like this:

```
--------------------------------
| nationality | bought  | sold |
--------------------------------
| Spanish     |     180 |   30 |
| Dutch       |      40 |  100 |
| English     |       0 |   90 |
| Stingish    |       0 |    0 |
--------------------------------
```

But I am not able to make it in one query,

I can do this:

```
SELECT persons.nationality, 
IFNULL(sum(trades.value), 0) as bought 
FROM trades 
RIGHT JOIN persons 
ON trades.buyer = persons.name 
GROUP BY nationality
```

To get the bought column and the same procedure for the sold column

```
SELECT persons.nationality, 
IFNULL(sum(trades.value), 0) as sold 
FROM trades 
RIGHT JOIN persons 
ON trades.seller = persons.name 
GROUP BY nationality
```

But I am not able to get it in one go as I want, any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fairly easy. You might be overthinking it.

```
SELECT 
p.nationality, 
ISNULL(SUM(sell.value), 0) AS sold, 
ISNULL(SUM(buy.value),0) AS bought

FROM persons p
LEFT JOIN trades sell
ON p.name = sell.seller
LEFT JOIN trades buy
ON p.name = buy.buyer

GROUP BY p.nationality
```